# How to build a VS2010 configuration of a VS2015 solution using MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I have a Visual Studio 2015 C++ project (solution) of which most build configurations use the VS2015 toolset. However, some configurations are set to use the VS2010 toolset because they link to 3rd party libraries built using VS2010.

All configurations build successfully from within the IDE, and the VS2015 configurations build successfully using MSBuild on the command line, but I am having trouble building the VS2010 configurations using MSBuild.

I invoke msbuild as follows:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat
>
> msbuild MSVC\mysln.sln /p:Configuration="myVS2010Config" /p:useenv=true

For the VS2010 configuration I get error:

> error C2039: 'gets': is not a member of 'std'

which suggests that the VS2015 compiler is being invoked, not the VS2010 compiler.

Why isn't MSBuild invoking the VS2010 tools?

Comment: A very standard mistake is to only change the toolset setting for *one* platform + configuration selection.  Typically just Debug + Win32 since that's the only one you test in the IDE.  Change the setting for all of them and verify that MSBuild is building the configuration and platform that you expected to be built.

Comment: Can you try adding /p:Platform="<Platform>" to your command line, just to be sure it is not defaulting to Any CPU or something like that?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The configuration in question definitely builds ok in the IDE.

Comment: I added `/p:Platform="Win32"` but the problem remains.

Comment: Hm, I suppose you know that the `PlatformToolset` property is part of the project configuration in the .vcxproj file, not the solution file. Have you checked that in each project the property is correct under the correct conditions? Hint: if you have many projects, you can extract the `<PlatformToolset>v100</PlatformToolset>` part into an own propertysheet and include that into all of your projects. Thats how it is working for us.